# how do i remove ubuntu 15.10 (thats encypt)whithout having windows installed

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, restore

Recently I tried dual booting Windows, and was very unsuccessful.  Instead of installing it as "something else," I chose the encrypt option, lost all  of my Windows files and drives.  So for the last few days I have been trying to get back to win 8.1 from a boot able USB stick, but every time I try to boot from the USB, but it automatically boots up as Ubuntu 15.10.

If some one can, tell me where I am going wrong.

Many thanks,

Anton Mzhelskiy

Comment: By remove, do you mean uninstall, remove encryption, or some thing else?

Comment: I would like to know how to completely remove Ubuntu 15.10 and put on win 8.1 , but when i go onto the boot menu and select my flash drive with windows 8.1 on it does nothing then  it reboots and starts up as Ubuntu 15.10. any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

To delete any Operating System from a computer (Linux, Windows, etc.), you can use GParted.  All you would need to do is:

1. Download the ISO:  http://gparted.org/download.php
2. Burn the ISO to a CD.
3. Keep the CD in the drive.
4. Reboot the computer.
5. If your computer does not automatically boot from the CD, enter BIOS or boot options (F1, F2, F9, F10, F12, ESC, case depends on computer), then select the CD.
6. You can select to use the defaults, but if your computer doesn't automatically go to the GUI, then go to the next step.  If it does go to the GUI, skip to step 9.
7. You will get asked what language and keyboard settings to use.  If you can read English, and have a standard QWERTY keyboard, you can use the defaults.  If not, languages and keyboard layouts are noted with a two digit number at each step.
8. If it has issues with your video card, configure it manually with Forcevideo, and then give it the desired resolution with widthxheight (1024x768 as an example).
9. By now, you should see the GUI.  Just open up GParted by double clicking the icon.
10. Now you should see a window listing the partitions on your hard drive.  Just select the one you wish to erase, and select delete.

More information can be found on their web site.  Here is more detailed info about booting from the command line:

http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=gparted-live-manual&lang=C#gparted-live-booting-gparted-live